# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units' issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a CNN for the small dataset which is I created. This is a cnn application that does classification. But it gives an error "TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'" . How can i solve this problem ?

File "D:......\painting_photos\yeni.py", line 31, in 
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))

TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'

line 31 is "classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))"

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense


classifier = Sequential()

# Convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# ANN
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

....
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which line of your code do you think the error message is talking about? Why, in your own words, do you think that line of code is correct? Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/ and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.